# How many bytes in BigQuery types

Tags: google-bigquery

How many bytes do the following types take up in BigQuery:

- Timestamp
- Datetime
- Date

My guess was that date could be stored in 2 bytes, and a timestamp perhaps 8, but I wasn't sure about that and it is not mentioned on the https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size of BigQuery's data types is as follows:

> ```
> Data type     Size
> INT64/INTEGER 8 bytes
> FLOAT64/FLOAT 8 bytes
> NUMERIC       16 bytes
> BOOL/BOOLEAN  1 byte
> STRING        2 bytes + the UTF-8 encoded string size
> BYTES         2 bytes + the number of bytes in the value
> DATE          8 bytes
> DATETIME      8 bytes
> TIME          8 bytes
> TIMESTAMP     8 bytes
> STRUCT/RECORD 0 bytes + the size of the contained fields
> GEOGRAPHY     16 bytes + 24 bytes * the number of vertices in the geography type (you can verify the number of vertices using the ST_NumPoints function)
> ```
>
> Null values for any data type are calculated as 0 bytes.
>
> A repeated column is stored as an array, and the size is calculated
>   based on the number of values. For example, an integer column (INT64)
>   that is repeated (ARRAY) and contains 4 entries is calculated
>   as 32 bytes (4 entries x 8 bytes).

See more details in [Data size calculation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data) section of [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) documentation

Comment: What about ARRAY? :)

Comment: I feel guilty just copy-pasting from documentation :o( usually this is not my type of questions to answer :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant any idea why a date is 8 bytes? That seems quite overkill unless someone is going to enter in a date like `Jan 1, 20193884949484` ?

Comment: @FI-Info, I was curious too... why there is 8 bytes reserved for dates when 9999 is explicitly stated as the max valid date, but I couldn't find any information, so I posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354823/why-is-bigquery-date-type-8-bytes-wide?noredirect=1#comment120806341_68354823