# How to query column metadata in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Within a BigQuery table, I need to return from a query each column size and data type of this table. Is this possible ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro       `SELECT * FROM myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: For the size of a table: `SELECT * FROM myDataset.__TABLES__`    The size of a column has to be calculated by hand and the columns have to be quered. For numeric datatypes multiplicate the size of the datatype with the amounts of non null entries. For string it is a bit more complicated. Here are the sizes of the datatype: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405969/bigquery-get-size-of-each-row-in-table

Answer (score 1):

You can view column data type with:

```
SELECT column_name,data_type FROM <MY_DATA_SET>.<MY_TABLE>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables